# Calculate the Diff between 2 dates

Tags: adodb

I have a simple calculated field in my Adodb query that calculates the difference between the due date column and a variable date.

Any idea why I'm getting syntax error missing an operator here?

```
",DATEDIFF('d' ,T1.[Due Date] ,#" & vDate & "#) as [Days Late] " & _
```